# How to remove/delete Podcast feed in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

What can I tell you, I don't really know how to expand on the title. I don't know how to remove a podcast feed.

I tried right clicking the podcast feed, when I do that it gives me two options:

- New Podcast Feed...
- Update All Podcasts

And none of the top menus have anything that suggests removal or deletion of a feed.

I'm astonished I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Podcast within Rhythmbox highlight the one you want to remove and then move the mouse up to the top left hand menu. Under edit there should be delete

Just tested this and I can right click individual feeds and delete them also from the small right click menu that pops up

[image: Delete Right Click]

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb right now. You must have a different version than me. On ubuntu11.10 I have rhythmbox2.90.1, which, for example, doesn't have any columns in the top window, so there is no column title "Feed" and if you drag the bottom window up as far as it can go the top window gets hidden. Mine was hidden by default, which makes it look like it isn't there. Anyways Thanks.